# Can not import Celery object from flask app

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to learn and integrate Celery with my flask app. I tried to the things mentioned in the link:
[Flask Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/celery/)

But I want to move all the async tasks in the separate module. So here is my git repository where I am making my changes:
[Beacons Repo](https://github.com/rajatguptarg/beacon-registry/tree/celery)

So I initialise my celery object in `beacons/__init__.py`:

```
from beacons.async import make_celery


mq_url = 'amqp://mq:mq@localhost/localhost'


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL=mq_url,
    CELERY_BACKEND=mq_url
)

log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '\n-------------------------------------\n'
    'TIME: %(asctime)s \n'
    'LEVEL: %(levelname)s \n'
    'MESSAGE: %(message)s \n'
    'FILE: %(pathname)s \n'
    'LINE: %(lineno)d'
    '\n-------------------------------------\n'))

app.logger.addHandler(log_handler)

app.register_blueprint(portal, url_prefix='/beacons')
app.register_blueprint(apis, url_prefix='/beacons/apis')
celery = make_celery(app)


__all__ = ['celery']
```

My `make_celery` is in `beacons/async/__init__.py` as follows:

```
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):

        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

And I created another module `beacons/tasks.py` which is:

```
from beacons import celery


@celery.task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And I am using this module in one of my views `beacons/portal/view/rest_apis.py` as follows:

```
from beacons.tasks import add

@apis.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_page():
    x = request.form.get('x')
    y = request.form.get('y')

    task = add.delay(x, y)
    return json_response(
        {"id": task.id}, status_code=200)
```

When I try to run the Celery worker and Flask App, I get this error:

```
    from beacons import celery
ImportError: cannot import name celery
```

How can I import celery object written in `beacons` module into its submodules or in the tasks itself. Please refer to the [Git Repo](https://github.com/rajatguptarg/beacon-registry/tree/celery) for complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I try to run your code and do not get this error. I comment out your system argument in your run.py and leave this code below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    port = '9000'
    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Then I execute python run.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wqNa.png)

Then I request flask with 127.0.0.1:9000 and got this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlKyX.png)

Flask works fine except a logging format error, and this error is out of topic.

Would you please post the command you executed and the directory you execute in? I think your working directory may lead this ImportError.

PS: The branch code your give in GitHub is different from the code post in this question.